# advice for retrieving functions and tables from intel 8061/8065 bin file (reverse engineering) from Ford EECV ECU

Tags: intel, rom, disassembly

I have under my disposal some Ford EECV bin files and my goal for the next few weeks is to retrieve the functions and tables and plot them out before going onto DIY hardware . .

Does anyone know which platforms to use to analyze Ford/Intel 8061/8065 bin files or possible disassemble them? I checked into the bin files today using notepad++ hex editor plugin and didn't get much strings except for 'Ford copyright 2002' but I do see some hex patterns floating around. . thus I would I find a disassembling platform or hack it with the 8061 manual?

Also, pardon my ignorance, but how do you regulars retrieve bin files? I know you can stick the ROM into the ROM reader but intuitively I feel that people also get bin files from the OBD port upon KOEO and get the 'ROM dump' from the RAM in the ECU. Is that the 'frontdoor' way of getting live data?

ps. pardon my use of semantics.

Comment: You may also want to check the reverse engineering stackexchange. Quick googling shows apparently you can find documenation for the Ford EEC system, including the instruction set. There are also a few disassemblers floating around. Of the standard tools, hex rays seems to have 8065. I'd assume binwalk will also be useful. Using the OBD port for dumps is only possible if the firmware supports it, and I know nothing about the Ford firmware. So *after* analyzing the dump you'll be able to tell :-)

Comment: thanks for your comment. . sure is a lot sub-stackexchanges around. but yea i think you're referring to the EEC-IV doc which mentions and compares the ISA of 8061,8065 and 8096. I don't know how analyzing the dump will tell me where it's from but maybe I will in time!

Comment: @JingyiTay Please [contact] Stack Exchange to merge your accounts, so you can comment on your question etc..